# STD Tag information

Tags: discussion, tags

I was doing some tag editing and found the STD tag: https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/std

It only has 1 question associated with but the tag can be many things, for example:

STD - Standard Input/Output of data
STD - Suspend To Disk (Hibernation mode)
STD - Sexually Transmitted Disease. But since we are in Linux my best bet is this is not it.

How to know what info to put in this Tag?

Answer (score 3):

If you come up with small issues like that feel free to edit the tag out, it can at all times be reverted as you know and does not hurt.

I have fixed this for now, thanks for the heads up and keep meta(ing) these!